# ¿Cómo personalizar el color de las líneas ,en un gráfico matplotlib con multiples líneas?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, jupyter

Dispongo de un DataFrame con 10 columnas, cuyo contenido deseo representar en un gráfico de líneas, para lo cual hago:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib as plt
(portfolio_df/portfolio_df.iloc[0]).plot(lw=1.5)
plt.show()
```

Las líneas se muestran correctamente, pero al generar el color automáticamente matplotlib, algún color se repite o es muy similar a otro.

Realizo otra prueba haciendo:

```
color = ['black', 'darkorange', 'green', 'blue', 'royalblue', 'darkviolet', 'fucsia', 'pinck', 'tomato', 'brown']

(portfolio_df/portfolio_df.iloc[0]).plot(color,  lw=1.5)
plt.show()
```

y me devuelve el error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_21873/1934979511.py in <module>
      1 color = ['black', 'darkorange', 'green', 'blue', 'royalblue', 'darkviolet', 'fucsia', 'pinck', 'tomato', 'brown']
      2 
----> 3 (portfolio_df/portfolio_df.iloc[0]).plot(color,  lw=1.5)
      4 plt.show()

~/anaconda3/envs/enri/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/plotting/_core.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    935                 if is_integer(x) and not data.columns.holds_integer():
    936                     x = data_cols[x]
--> 937                 elif not isinstance(data[x], ABCSeries):
    938                     raise ValueError("x must be a label or position")
    939                 data = data.set_index(x)

~/anaconda3/envs/enri/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   3509             if is_iterator(key):
   3510                 key = list(key)
-> 3511             indexer = self.columns._get_indexer_strict(key, "columns")[1]
   3512 
   3513         # take() does not accept boolean indexers

~/anaconda3/envs/enri/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in _get_indexer_strict(self, key, axis_name)
   5794             keyarr, indexer, new_indexer = self._reindex_non_unique(keyarr)
   5795 
-> 5796         self._raise_if_missing(keyarr, indexer, axis_name)
   5797 
   5798         keyarr = self.take(indexer)

~/anaconda3/envs/enri/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in _raise_if_missing(self, key, indexer, axis_name)
   5854                 if use_interval_msg:
   5855                     key = list(key)
-> 5856                 raise KeyError(f"None of [{key}] are in the [{axis_name}]")
   5857 
   5858             not_found = list(ensure_index(key)[missing_mask.nonzero()[0]].unique())

KeyError: "None of [Index(['black', 'darkorange', 'green', 'blue', 'royalblue', 'darkviolet',\n       'fucsia', 'pinck', 'tomato', 'brown'],\n      dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"
```

¿Cómo puedo personalizar estos colores.?. Agradeceré ayuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estabas muy cerca. Debes usar el parámetro llamado `color` (y por cierto el color "fucsia" no existe en matplotlib, se escribe "fuchsia").

Un ejemplo, primero creo unos cuantos datos medio aleatorios (basados en una senoide con ruido):

```
import numpy as np
x = np.linspace(0, 3*np.pi, 50)
y = np.sin(x)
data = np.random.random(size=(len(x), 10))
for i in range(10):
  data[:,i] *= y
  data[:,i] += i*0.2
```

Ahora los convierto en un dataframe y lo ploteo con los colores por defecto:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
ax = df.plot()
ax.legend(loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5))
```

Sale así:

[image: Colores por defecto]

Ahora cambiando a los colores que tú querías:

```
colors = ['black', 'darkorange', 'green', 'blue', 'royalblue', 'darkviolet', 'fuchsia', 'pink', 'tomato', 'brown']
ax = df.plot(color = colors)
ax.legend(loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5))
```

Y el resultado es:

[image: Resultado deseado]